# identify button click event using text jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have three buttons which are automatically generated with a jQuery plugin.

```
<button class="execute">Invoice1</button>
<button class="execute">Invoice2</button>
<button class="execute">Invoice3</button>
```

I want to write jQuery (JS) code to update form textbook only click Invoice2 button.
So, I want to write jQuery to identify it using text on button. I can write jQuery to update text box, but I don't know how to separately click Invoice2 button from others. I can't add another class or id because the buttons are generated automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) like,

```
$('button:contains("Invoice2")').on('click',function(){
    alert('Invoice 2 clicked');
});
```

This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/62vkoz4w/) can help you more.

Comment: Might be more efficient to use `$('.execute').eq(1).on('click' ...`

Comment: @vch not if your read OPs question. Might be in a different order or whatever.. so `eq(1)` is not an option.

Comment: @vch if there is only 3 buttons

Comment: What if they are not in the same order, which is given in Question?

Comment: Good points, though I didn't see in the question where it said their might be more than three or the order would be random. Regardless, you're right that the answer is more flexible in those cases.

Comment: This would be practical as I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
 $('.execute').click(function(){
      if($(this).html() == 'Invoice2') {
       //Do your stuff
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :Contain function in the jquery and check weather the text contains Invoice2 or not if yes than execute the code. Here is the sample of the code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button:contains("Invoice2")').on('click',function(){
    alert("Invocie2 input was clicked");
});
});
</script>
```